# Problems with amsart and no \maketitle

Tags: amsart

I am using the amsart document class and I want to design the title page myself.

My problem is that the absence of the \maketitle command seems to break some things.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyAuthor}
\begin{titlepage}
  My own title Page
\end{titlepage}
% \maketitle
\newpage
Rest of the document
\end{document}
```

My problem is that if there is no \maketitle, then the custom headers and footers of the amsart document class won't be displayed. Also, I am not sure if there is something else that is broken that I am currently missing.

Since this is my first post, I hope that I really have given a minimal working example. Feel free to suggest improvements in my post. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have already checked the documentation of the \maketitle command in the amsart class but because of my limited knowledge this wasn't helpfull.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Is there any reason you can't copy the definition of `\maketitle` from `amsart` and redefine it to produce the style of title you want?

Comment: This could very well be possible, but the problem is that I do not know which part of the \maketitle definition actually handles the optics of the title page. As I already said, I do not know much about most of the commands there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import just the part of `\maketitle` that sets the headers. You also need to uppercase the title.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeheaders}{%
  \begingroup
  \toks@\@xp{\shortauthors}\@temptokena\@xp{\shorttitle}%
  \toks4{\def\\{ \ignorespaces}}% defend against questionable usage
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \@nx\markboth{\the\toks4
      \@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\@temptokena}}}%
  \@tempa
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyAuthor}

\begin{titlepage}
  My own title Page
\end{titlepage}

\makeheaders

\newpage
Rest of the document
\newpage
Rest of the document
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much! I am going to try this and come back with a response if this works for me. Also, are You aware of anything else that could break with regards to the amsart class if I am not using the \maketitle command?

Comment: I just noticed that the title doesn't have the right shape. It should be all uppercase I think.

Comment: @dr01 Now fixed.

Comment: Thank You, Now it works for me!